# How can I find the last occurence of a pattern in a string and get everything before it in unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, substring

Please help me get everything before the last occurrence of "_". My string looks like.

```
abc_defg_hijkl_20160101.txt
```

and I only need the part before last "_"

```
abc_defg_hijkl
```

I am trying to use cut but again cannot use it as the number of underscore('_') is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BASH's string manipulation you can trim part after last `_` from input:

```
s='abc_defg_hijkl_20160101.txt'
echo "${s%_*}"

abc_defg_hijkl
```

If you are not using BASH then you can use this `sed` command to remove part after last `_` from input:

```
echo "$s" | sed 's/_[^_]*$//'
```

Comment: Yes , this worked perfectly. Thanks for the speedy response. Sorry if the question was too naive as I am new at shell scripting.